# Why would $(2,3\pi)$ and $(2,-3\pi)$ be different points in polar coordinates?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am looking at this problem solution and it says $(2,3\pi)$ and $(2,-3\pi)$ represent two different points in polar coordinates. Why would they be different? In my opinion, since I am adding $6\pi$ (which is a multiple of $2\pi$) to $-3\pi$, they should be the same. Even plotting the two points gave me an indication that they are the same. Where am I mistaken?

EDIT: [Here is a similar problem part (b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq32E.png)

Comment: I think you are right on this one.

Comment: Do you have the text of the problem?

Comment: it's on an online homework platform. It just tells me if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Is it possible you're flipping the radial and angle coordinates?  Maybe for their notation it's the other way around.

Comment: Are $(2,\frac{51\pi}{4})$ and $(2,-\frac{51\pi}{4})$ also the same? This was another question.

Comment: Screencap the problem and show us that it gave you the answer you're saying.  I'm skeptical.

Comment: @JohnSamples I added a screenshot of the similar problem (see part b). It randomizes the numbers every time you attempt it.

Comment: @JohnDouma I have edited the question and included a screenshot of a similar problem.  The only difference if that we don't have an integer multiple of $\pi$ in it. Would that make a difference?